# Не могу умножить два числа и добавить в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

[image: mysql php]

$sql = "INSERT INTO satylgandar (name, kuda, price, summa, (price*summa) as osumma, data) VALUES
('$args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzmIB.jpg)', '$args[2]', '$args[3]', '$args[4]', '$args[5]', '$args[6]')";
$connection->query($sql);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args[5]=$args[3]*$args[4];
$sql = "INSERT INTO satylgandar (name, kuda, price, summa, osumma, data) VALUES ('$args[1]', '$args[2]', '$args[3]', '$args[4]', '$args[5]', '$args[6]')";
$connection->query($sql);
```

Не?

Comment: )) ща попробую) @DaaGER

Comment: все спасибо) чета туплю)